# "Project Settings" are not recognized by Xcode when copied to a new computer?

Tags: xcode

Why is it that when I go to the Xcode's File -> Project Settings... and modify:

[image]

and in "Advanced" I also modify:

[image]

And then copy the whole project folder to a new computer and try to open it with Xcode there, I get:

[image]

Like it doesn't see those settings.

How do I copy those???